# Image interpolation in Google Chrome vs GIMP

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, image-resizing

I have a large png image (950x500px) which I have been scaling down using CSS to 500px wide (and 263 high). Before putting this webpage online I decided to scale the image using GIMP as scaling images with CSS is bad practice. However there is a noticeable reduction in image quality when I scale the image using GIMP rather than CSS in Google Chrome even though both images are png and have identical dimensions. I have tried using all four compression methods offered by GIMP (`None`, `Linear`, `Cubic` and `Sinc (Lanczos3)`) and none of them match the image quality given by Google Chrome.

What compression method does Google Chrome use to give such high-quality image scaling and how can I achieve this offline?

Comment: Sadly this is still a valid question in 2021 ... I got a friend to scale my image using photoshop and the difference was remarkable. I was resizing a PNG logo from 89x127 to 69x101 and the text blurred after the resize in Gimp no matter which interpolation I chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the answer to your question here: [How web browsers resize images](http://entropymine.com/resamplescope/notes/browsers/)

Chrome seems to be using several algorithms depending on the scaling factor:

> With a very slight downscale (557 to 555 pixels), Chrome uses the same
>   linear interpolation as when upscaling. (The fact that this graph is
>   disconnected is an artifact of the way ResampleScope works, and has
>   nothing to do with Chrome.)
>
> But look what happens if we downscale just a bit more, to 543 pixels:
>   […] We get a completely different result: clearly a 3-lobed Lanczos
>   filter. Chrome’s strategy may be to use Lanczos when reducing an image
>   by more than 2.5%.

If you have to do it yourself (to get more control on the result), `Cubic` is usually the best bet scaling up and `Sinc (Lanczos3)` for scaling down. 

If you scale the image yourself, you know how it will look on all browsers.

**Note:** *There are more and more computers equipped with high resolution displays (around 4 times the pixel density of a classic display). You may want to check how images look on those computers. There is a high chance they are scaled up by the browser.*

Comment: I can not get GIMP to resize a nice version of the file. using `convert -resize` gives much better results for me

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but I was struggling with an image resize in Gimp yesterday. When I compared the image resized in Gimp with the image automatically resized in Chrome (and Safari), there was a visible difference.

I was resizing a PNG logo from 89x127 to 69x101 and the text blurred after the resize in Gimp no matter which interpolation I chose.

Thanks to the comment above saying that ImageMagick gave a better result when resizing an image, I found this article: [Efficient Image Resizing With ImageMagick](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/efficient-image-resizing-with-imagemagick/)

The command from the article, despite its claims to be indistinguishable from Photoshop, did not produce a result that matched Chrome, however one of the commenters added a command that did create an image that produced the closest result (barring the resize my friend did in Photoshop):

```
convert SOURCE_IMAGE -resize OUTPUT_WIDTH -quality 90 -unsharp 0x0.55+0.55+0.008 OUTPUT_IMAGE
```

I think the trick lies mainly in the sharpening. I've tried different settings and can't exactly match Chrome, but this came pretty darn close.

For completeness, here is the command from the article. Please read the article for a full explanation of how it works:

```
mogrify -path OUTPUT_PATH -filter Triangle -define filter:support=2 -thumbnail OUTPUT_WIDTH -unsharp 0.25x0.25+8+0.065 -dither None -posterize 136 -quality 82 -define jpeg:fancy-upsampling=off -define png:compression-filter=5 -define png:compression-level=9 -define png:compression-strategy=1 -define png:exclude-chunk=all -interlace none -colorspace sRGB -strip INPUT_PATH
```